# Angularjs controller from string - success and failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, dashboard

I'm trying to create a Dashboard framework, taking inspiration from sdorra version: https://github.com/sdorra/angular-dashboard-framework

But I can't get (read: I can't understand) how the working version works.

To be more specific I can't understand how to register a controller so that a widget in the dahsboard can pick it up based on it's name.

I have a failing plunkr and the provider function from the original author of the framework below

my Plunkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/M9Cpzl5QkKAYeISfwV5K?p=preview

in which this code doesn't work as I expect:

```
 widgetProvider.setWidget("htmlWidget", 
      {
       name: "HTML Widget", 
       contentTemplateUrl : "htmlcontent.html",
       controller: "htmlWidgetController"
     })
```

And the good code:

https://github.com/sdorra/angular-dashboard-framework/blob/master/src/scripts/provider.js

At this point any help would be appreciated like link to well-written tutorials.

Comment: When WidetProvider.setWidget is called, it'll look for controller called "htmlWidgetController" within the app. That can be angular.module('widget', []).controller('htmlWidgetController') or function htmlWidgetController($scope){..}. As long as the controller is defined BEFORE this is called, you're fine. You can also look into [$ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) for loading files when you need them.

Comment: I guess the app is working properly in this sense. the upper div of the included html correctly display the array of things. Is there something I am missing in your suggestion?